# Python Index out of range Error in lib loop issue

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl, xlrd

everything's fine? I hope so.

I'm dealing with this issue: List index out of range. -

Error message:
c:\Users.....\Documents\t.py:41: FutureWarning: As the xlwt package is no longer maintained, the xlwt engine will be removed in a future version of pandas. This is the only engine in pandas that supports writing in the xls format. Install openpyxl and write to an xlsx file instead. You can set the option io.excel.xls.writer to 'xlwt' to silence this warning. While this option is deprecated and will also raise a warning, it can be globally set and the warning suppressed.
read_file.to_excel(planilhaxls, index = None, header=True)

[image: error]

The goal: I need to create a loop that store a specific line of a worksheet such as sheet_1.csv, this correspondent line in sheet_2.csv and a third sheet also, stored in 3 columns in a sheet_output.csv

Issue: It's getting an index error out of range that I don't know what to do

Doubt: There is any other way that I can do it?

- The code is below:
  (Please, ignore portuguese comments)

```
import xlrd as ex
import pyautogui as pag
import os
import pyperclip as pc
import pandas as pd
import pygetwindow as pgw
import openpyxl

#Inputs
numerolam = int(input('Escolha o número da lamina: '))
amostra = input('Escoha a amostra: (X, Y, W ou Z): ')
milimetro_inicial = int(input("Escolha o milimetro inicial: "))
milimetro_final = int(input("Escolha o milimetro final: "))
tipo = input("Escolha o tipo - B para Branco & E para Espelho: ")
linha = int(input("Escolha a linha da planilha: "))

# Conversão de código
if tipo == 'B':
    tipo2 = 'BRA'
else: 
    tipo2 = 'ESP'

#Arquivo xlsx
#planilhaxlsx = f'A{numerolam}{amostra}{milimetro_inicial}{tipo2}.xlsx'
#planilhaxls = f'A{numerolam}{amostra}{milimetro_inicial}{tipo2}.xls'
#planilhacsv = f'A{numerolam}{amostra}{milimetro_inicial}{tipo2}.csv'
#planilhacsv_ = f'A{numerolam}{amostra}{milimetro_final}{tipo2}.csv'
#arquivoorigin = f'A{numerolam}{amostra}{milimetro_inicial}{tipo2}.opj'

#Pasta
pasta =  f'L{numerolam}{amostra}'

while milimetro_inicial < milimetro_final:
    planilhaxlsx = f'A{numerolam}{amostra}{milimetro_inicial}{tipo2}.xlsx'
    planilhaxls = f'A{numerolam}{amostra}{milimetro_inicial}{tipo2}.xls'
    planilhacsv = f'A{numerolam}{amostra}{milimetro_inicial}{tipo2}.csv'
    planilhacsv_ = f'A{numerolam}{amostra}{milimetro_final}{tipo2}.csv'
    arquivoorigin = f'A{numerolam}{amostra}{milimetro_inicial}{tipo2}.opj'
    
    # Converte o arquivo .csv para .xls e .xlsx
    read_file = pd.read_csv(planilhacsv)
    read_file.to_excel(planilhaxls, index = None, header=True)
    #read_file.to_excel(planilhaxlsx, index = None, header=True)
    
    # Abre o arquivo .xls com o xlrd - arquivo excel.
    book = ex.open_workbook(planilhaxls)
    sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)

    # Declaração de variáveis.
    coluna_inicial = 16 # Q - inicia em 0
    valor = []
    index = 0


    # Loop que armazena o valor da linha pela coluna Q-Z na variável valor 0-(len-1)
    while coluna_inicial < 25:
        **#ERRO NA LINHA ABAIXO**
        **temp = sh.cell_value(linha, coluna_inicial)**
        valor.append(temp) # Adiciona o valor
        print(index)
        print(valor[index])
        index +=1 
        coluna_inicial += 1

    # Abre planilha de saída
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    #Inicia loop de escrita
    colunas = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
    idx_colunas = 0
    contador_loop = colunas[idx_colunas]
    linha_loop = 1
    index_out = 0
    s = f'{contador_loop}{linha_loop}'

    print(s)

    while linha_loop < len(valor):
        valor[index_out] = "{}".format(valor[index_out])
        ws[s].value = valor[index_out]
        print(valor[index_out] + ' feito')
        linha_loop += 1
        idx_colunas += 1
        index_out += 1

    # Salva planilha de saída
    wb.save("teste.xlsx")
    milimetro_inicial += 1
```

Comment: I would recommend posting the full stacetrace (error) that is being output as it would help narrow down your problem.

Comment: Please include the traceback as text. But also simplify the code, this is too long for us really to help. It's also seems to make little use of the openpyxl API.

Comment: This is the error: c:\Users\PESSOAL\Documents\t.py:41: FutureWarning: As the xlwt package is no longer maintained, the xlwt engine will be removed in a future version of pandas. This is the only engine in pandas that supports writing in the xls format. Install openpyxl and write to an xlsx file instead. You can set the option io.excel.xls.writer to 'xlwt' to silence this warning. While this option is deprecated and will also raise a warning, it can be globally set and the warning suppressed.        
  read_file.to_excel(planilhaxls, index = None, header=True)

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on this line

```
temp = sh.cell_value(linha, coluna_inicial)
```

There are two index params used **linha** and **coluna_inicial**, 'linha' appears to be a static value so the problem would seem to be with  'coluna_inicial' which gets increased by 1 each iteration

```
coluna_inicial += 1
```

The loop continues while 'coluna_inicial' value is less than 25. I suggest you check number of columns in the sheet 'sh' using

```
sh.ncols
```

either for debugging or as the preferred upper value of your loop. If this is less than 25 you will get the index error once 'coluna_inicial' value exceeds the 'sh.ncols' value.

<---------------Additional Information---------------->
Since this is an xls file there would be no need for delimiter settings, your code as is should open it correctly. However since the xls workbook to be opened is determined by params entered by the user at the start presumably meaning there are a number in the directory to choose from, are you sure you are checking the xls file your code run is opening? Also if there is more than one sheet in the workbook(s) are you opening the correct sheet?
You can print the workbook name to be sure which one is being opened. Also by adding verbosity to the **open_workbook** command (level 2 should be high enough), it will upon opening the book, print in console details of the sheets available including number of rows and columns in each.

```
print(planilhaxls)
book = ex.open_workbook(planilhaxls, verbosity=2)
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
print(sh.name)
```

E.g.

BOF: op=0x0809 vers=0x0600 stream=0x0010 buildid=14420 buildyr=1997 -> BIFF80
**sheet 0('Sheet1') DIMENSIONS: ncols=21 nrows=21614**
BOF: op=0x0809 vers=0x0600 stream=0x0010 buildid=14420 buildyr=1997 ->
BIFF80
**sheet 1('Sheet2') DIMENSIONS: ncols=13 nrows=13**

the **print(sh.name)** as shown checks the name of the sheet that **'sh'** is assigned to.

Comment: Woah, I had a light! There is only 1 column, but in excel it shows normal as it is... Is there any delimiter issue?

Comment: @Grabas I have added some additional information in the answer under the section marked --Additional Information--